# Problem with layer order in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

When I move a vector layer at the top of all the other layers this action doesn't translate on the map canvas. It still exists under other layers there. In the image below layer namned "my_12 (Ytskikt med markslag)" is second in the layer panel but it still appears below the two raster layers in the map canvas.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details and a screenshot. Otherwise, it's almost impossible to help you and the question risks to be closed. To avoid that unpleasant exprerience, edit your question an add details.

Comment: I just did. But it still says that the question is closed. Can you open it up or do I have to post a new question?

Comment: Just to be sure: are there any features on the layer `my_12 (Ytskikt med markslag)` in the region of the map canvas? If you uncheck all other layers and only keep this one: do you see something? Because the other vector layer `Kullaberg Höjkurvor` is clearly drawn on top of the raster layer. Did you somehow set the color to transparency? Adding another screenshot showing the settings of the styling panel could help to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Confirm you've checked the box on the layer to have it active in your map.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had a wrong style template on the layer. That was causing the issue.

Comment: Please keep in mind [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).